# WPF MediaElement radomly crashing in background without error

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mp4, mediaelement

I'm attempting to stream video using WPF MediaElement, but i've become stuck on a rather peculiar problem.

The issue is that randomly, perhaps 1 time out of 10 on average, the MediaElement just freezes after the first frame. There is no error in MediaFailed event, and when it happens, the application uses 100% of the CPU core until closed.

The files i'm streaming is mp4 video from GfyCat, for example 
http://zippy.gfycat.com/AjarHealthyAfricancivet.mp4. I've tried downloading them and playing from disk, same issue. I can also reproduce with a new  blank project only containing a MediaElement.

I also tried playing them using the WPF MediaPlayer, same issue. Software rendering the window does not help. The problem seem to occur much more often when running the exe outside of visual studio, but it still sometimes happens while debugging. It also seem to happen more often on monitors other then the primary.

Every time i set a source url, i get a "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find the media file. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00D1197): Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D1197". I can work around this by simply setting the url again, so i'm not sure if it's a part of the problem or not.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem, or is MediaElement just not the right tool for reliable looping video ?

Comment: how you are applying MediaElement source  ? have you added it in your application?

Comment: please try chanding your MediaElement source with some other file of mp4

Comment: @Ashok Rathod, i bind the source to an URI in my viewmodel. However i also tried setting the source in code, with no difference.  

I tried some various video files. AVI plays fine all the time. mp4 downloaded from youtube (10mb size) has the same problem while debugging, but failes every time when run with exe. MKV does not play at all, but fails with "0xC00D0FEA Media file download failed."

Answer (score 2):

I am have the same problem with looping the video. Sometimes it just don't play, and after that it can't play anymore.

But I had this COMException too, and in my case, the video really was not being copied to output, then it raised the exception, in my case was just a file name mistake or file not existent that was rising this exception.

There's a memory leak on this MediaElement too, for me, this solved it:

```
    private void CleanUpVideos()
    {
        videoElement.Close();
        videoElement.Clock = null;
        videoElement.Source = null;
        videoElement = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

Comment: @AnkurTripathi This code are currently in production and working for Windows XP at least. I need to review it to know if something more were done.